# Convert an html Object to a String and Output the String using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, html-parsing

I'm ultimately trying to find all image tags on a page and print out the ones without alt tags.

Right now I have this:

```
var str = '<img id="img1" /><img id="img2" /><img id="img3" /><img id="img4" alt="ASDF" title="" /><img id="img5" alt="" /><img id="img6" title="" />';
var imagesWithoutAlt = $( str ).filter( 'img:not([alt])' );
var newString = new String( $( imagesWithoutAlt ).clone().html());
$(document.body).append($('<textarea rows="6" cols="40"/>').text( newString );
```

But this is failing to output anything. Help?

Comment: you need to wrap the imagesWithoutAlt clone in an element and get that element's html.

Comment: OK. I'm new to jQuery, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pkdtg/

```
var str = '<img id="img1" /><img id="img2" /><img id="img3" /><img id="img4" alt="ASDF" title="" /><img id="img5" alt="" /><img id="img6" title="" />';
var imagesWithoutAlt = $(str).filter('img:not([alt])');
var newString = $(imagesWithoutAlt).clone().wrapAll("<div />").parent().html();
$(document.body).append($('<textarea rows="6" cols="40"/>').text(newString));​
```

I added `.wrapAll("<div />").parent()`

Comment: Thank you for the prompt help!